# How to fix Laravel AJAX request not working

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel

I am trying to store the data from multiple ratio buttons to the database.
And the AJAX post request is below:

```
$.ajax({  
                url: '{{ route("checklist.store") }}',  
                method:'POST',  
                data:{
                    _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
                    data1 : value1,
                    data2 : value2
                    },  
                success:function(data){  
                    console.log('success');
                }  
            });
```

The message in the console is printed on the console but the item is not created in the database.

Store method in controller :

```
    $hacInspectionsChecklistTable = HacInspectionsChecklistTable::create($request->all());
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give more information about the controller.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I have store method in the backend and just sending the data using AJAX call to it

Comment: And i am using datatables for this

Comment: Do you have data1 and data2 in the $fillable property of your model?

Comment: Yes i do have those in my model as $fillable
The entry is created if i use normal form post method but not using AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Check your Model first :

```
protected $fillable = [
 'data1', 'data2'
];
```

If everything is ok you can try with something like that

#### Ajax code :

```
$.ajax({  
   url: '{{ route("route.store") }}',  
   method:'POST',  
   data:{
         _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
         data1 : value1,
         data2 : value2
        },  
        success:function(data){  
          if(data=="created"){
            console.log('success');
          }
        }  
});
```

#### Route

`Route::post('/youroute', [YourController::class, 'store'])->name('route.store');`

#### Controller

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $data = new Model();
    $data->data1 = $request->data1;
    $data->data2 = $request->data2;
    $data->save();

    return response()->json('created');
}
```